# branching mode in toplink/eclipselink

Tags: java, orm, eclipselink, toplink

can somebody please tell wether branching mode is supported in any of the two technologies eclipselink or toplink?Please provide reference or any documentation link for your answer thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by branching mode?

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/cdo/documentation/relnotes_30/relnotes-3.0.html @Chris kindly see this branching is explained here. Thanks for your interest :)

Comment: Still don't understand what you are asking or after.  CDO and it's branching do not seem related to ORM.  What you might be after is maybe storing historical data?  https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/History